# Ubuntu 14.04 AWUS036H (v5) continually re-initializes - never succeeds completely

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, drivers

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running on a Dell Precision M3800.  I need to use two wifi cards on this machine (long story) and I have had the internal Intel 7260 working along side a Netgear..something (rtl8187 chipset).. for quite some time with no problems.

I decided to replace the Netgear with an AWUS036H because it uses the same chipset and supports an auxiliary antenna.

However, upon plugging in the AWUS036H, I see this in my syslog:

```
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): bringing up device.
ModemManager[932]: <warn>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4': not supported by any plugin
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): preparing device.
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
kernel: [   72.933533] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan3: link is not ready
wpa_supplicant[1411]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3) supports 4 scan SSIDs
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
NetworkManager[1226]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): supplicant interface state: ready -> disconnected
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3) supports 4 scan SSIDs
wpa_supplicant[1411]: wlan3: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
wpa_supplicant[1411]: wlan3: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
kernel: [   73.088767] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 31
NetworkManager[1226]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/net/wlan3, iface: wlan3)
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): device state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [30 10 36]
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): cleaning up...
NetworkManager[1226]: <warn> (25) failed to find interface name for index
NetworkManager[1226]: (nm-system.c:766):nm_system_iface_get_flags: runtime check failed: (iface != NULL)
NetworkManager[1226]: <error> [1416857019.131304] [nm-system.c:768] nm_system_iface_get_flags(): (unknown): failed to get interface link object
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> radio killswitch /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/ieee80211/phy22/rfkill24 disappeared
kernel: [   73.664842] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
kernel: [   73.799603] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8187
kernel: [   73.799607] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: [   73.799609] usb 3-4: Product: RTL8187_Wireless
kernel: [   73.799610] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Manufacturer_Realtek_RTL8187_
kernel: [   73.799612] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 00B0CA945E30
kernel: [   73.932414] ieee80211 phy23: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
kernel: [   73.932579] ieee80211 phy23: hwaddr 00:b0:ca:94:5e:30, RTL8187vB (default) V1 + rtl8225z2, rfkill mask 2
mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 32: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4"
mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 32 was not an MTP device
kernel: [   73.942221] rtl8187: Customer ID is 0xFF
kernel: [   73.942569] rtl8187: wireless switch is on
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> rfkill25: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/ieee80211/phy23/rfkill25) (driver rtl8187)
NetworkManager[1226]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/net/wlan3, iface: wlan3)
NetworkManager[1226]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/net/wlan3, iface: wlan3): no ifupdown configuration found.
kernel: [   73.965038] systemd-udevd[1528]: renamed network interface wlan1 to wlan3
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): new 802.11 WiFi device (driver: 'rtl8187' ifindex: 26)
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/24
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
NetworkManager[1226]: <info> (wlan3): bringing up device.
```

This loops indefinitely and the device never becomes usable.

I've removed Network Manager completely, that didn't help.  I removed the 7260 drivers and blacklisted them, and that didn't help.  I plugged it in to another 14.04 box, where no other wireless cards are present, and it works.

Here's the output from lshw (if I time it just right, I can pick up the AWUS, but it's only listed for a few moments before it disappears):

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 6b
   serial: e8:2a:ea:43:ef:d8
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.15.0-031500-generic firmware=23.214.9.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:54 memory:f7900000-f7901fff

*-network:1
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 3
   bus info: usb@3:4
   logical name: wlan3
   serial: 00:b0:ca:94:5e:30
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8187 driverversion=3.15.0-031500-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

lsmod:

```
rtl8187                65286  0 
mac80211              663788  2 rtl8187,iwlmvm
cfg80211              514187  4 iwlwifi,mac80211,rtl8187,iwlmvm
eeprom_93cx6           13344  1 rtl8187
iwlwifi               185872  1 iwlmvm
```

Any ideas?  I'm kind of at a loss here, especially since another card that uses rtl8187 works fine on this laptop.

Thanks!